# error while using gnuplot in pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, gnuplot

I am using pgfplots and tikz library for generating some figures.
my problem is that I can not use gnuplot within pgfplots.
I tried to compile the following code bu seemingly the gnuplot is not recognized.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[view={0}{90}] 
\addplot3[contour gnuplot] {x*y};  
\end{axis} \end{tikzpicture}
```

Anyone knows which package I should include?

Comment: Use `pdflatex --shell-escape yourfile`. Yourfile is actually your tex file. Make sure that the gnuplot executable is in system's path.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Compile this with `--shell-escape`. Also make sure that gnuplot is installed and is in system's path:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat = 1.7}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

    \begin{axis}[
        %   title = {$x \times y$}
        , xlabel = $x$
            , ylabel = $y$
            , domain = -1:1
            , y domain = -1:1
        , enlargelimits
        , view = {0}{90}
        , x tick label style={
             /pgf/number format/.cd,
             fixed,
             fixed zerofill,
             precision=1,
             /tikz/.cd
            }
          , y tick label style={
             /pgf/number format/.cd,
             fixed,
             fixed zerofill,
             precision=1,
             /tikz/.cd
            }
        ]

\addplot3[contour gnuplot] {x*y};  
    \end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Just beautiful.

Comment: I don't know how can I compile with --shell--escape? I'm using win7

Comment: @batistacori Which editor you are using to type your latex code?

Comment: solved thanks... I replaced my \begin{axis} with yours.

Comment: @HarishKumar another problem occurs. when I change the function of the plot. nothing is changed in pdf view. it is always like the above image

Comment: @batistacori You have to adjust the domain of x and y. If you give more details of the function, it will be useful. Or may be open a new question?